# Extract jasmine specs descriptions and insert them in jsDoc documentation as @description

Tags: javascript, jasmine, gulp, karma-runner, jsdoc

I have recently started using jsDoc to document the codebase. I was wondering if I can make use of the specs that I wrote using jasmine for the modules that I document. There is a ton of information about each method in those Specs. Is there any way to retrieve that information?

```
describe('.add()', function () {
    ...
    it('throws error if "key" argument is not String type', function () {
        expect(function () {
            collection.add(123, 1);
        }).toThrow(new Error('Add failed, argument "key" is not String type'));
    });
    ...
});
```

I get a lot of information from these specs and I think it's a pitty to waste this information. I would like to move it into `@description`. I suspect that there are two ways this could be done. One from jsDoc using a plugin or a gulp command, and the other way around would be from karma, when running the tests, it could automatically append documentation data of the functions inside the soruce file.

```
.add()
    adds value to collection
    throws error if "key" argument is not String type
    throws error if "key" argument is undefined
    throws error if "value" argument is undefined
    throws error if "metadata" argument is not Object type {key:value}
    throws error if it tries to attach metadata to value that is not Object type {key:value}
    returns stored value
    overwrites previous value if using same key
    appends metadata to stored value
```